# CICS Subprograms

Tags: cobol, cics

I have a requirement that states to have a Menu Screen containing 10 options and user can select a option and jump to appropriate screen.I have created a Trans-ID for Menu Screen.Do i need to create Trans-ID for all the 10 options?.I have searched for this type of Requirement and all of them involves creating the Trans-ID for each sub screen so that the screen can be refreshed and return to same screen until user selects to go back to main-screen.
I am new to CICS-COBOL Programming and not sure why we need to create Trans-ID for each screen.Is this the global format or is there any other approach available?

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to use a tranid per screen/function in this scenario. You could actually use one transid and even one program in a [pseudoconversational style](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGMCP_5.4.0/applications/developing/recovery/dfht2c00192.html).

You would use a commarea to hold the state of the interaction with the user at the terminal, so when the user picks an option and the next 'leg' of the pseudoconversation invokes the transaction and program again, you can determine in that program what has just been received from the terminal, what to do with it and what response to send back to the terminal. This process simply repeats until the business function completes and you can end with the default menu again.